# Is EFT (Escape From Tarkov) halal to play

Tags: riba, gambling

With virtual money I buy shooting equipment and there is no paying with real money (I have a stash where I have my things and other players don't have access to it, I earn money by selling things and doing missions). My player and other players are connected to the map (the game is online), some survive and collect things from the map, some lose their equipment whan they die. Players can take other people's items when they kill them. In the game they have missions where I have to give something, and in return I get xp, something and an unknown reward. Now is there interest and gamling here and taking otheres stuff, is that ok, because this is a game.

“And for their taking interest even though it was forbidden for them, and their wrongful appropriation of other people’s property. We have prepared for those among them who reject faith a grievous punishment” (4:161)